# How to Show Google Search Results in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a Google search to my Android application. But I only need results from Google. I just need results. For example, when I type "Stackoverflow" in Google, I want to get only the results.

What package and API can I use for this?

Answer (score -1):

One of the simple method i would suggest is go to google a create a custom search engine...

and then use webview() in app

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work for me. I just need results. To `string` result data only.